# WebGL: glsl attributes issue, getProgramParameter returns wrong number of attributes

Tags: glsl, webgl

I'm making a simple WebGL demo. I have a simple vertex shader that takes two attributes and some uniforms. Here is the code:

```
attribute vec3 v_position;
attribute vec3 v_normal;

uniform mat4   mvMatrix;
uniform mat4   pMatrix;
uniform mat3   normalMatrix;
uniform vec3   lightPosition;



// Color to fragment program
varying vec3 transformedNormal;
varying vec3 lightDir;

void main(void) 
{ 
  // Get surface normal in eye coordinates
  transformedNormal = normalMatrix * v_normal;

  // Get vertex position in eye coordinates
  vec4 position4 = mvMatrix * vec4(v_position.xyz,1.0);
  vec3 position3 = position4.xyz / position4.w;

      // Get vector to light source
  lightDir = normalize(lightPosition - position3);


  // Don't forget to transform the geometry!
  gl_Position = pMatrix * mvMatrix * vec4(v_position.xyz,1.0);
}
```

For some reason when I call

```
gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES);
```

I get a count of 1 when I should be getting 2;

I'm not sure what is wrong here.  If you need it this is the fragment shader that goes with it:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif 

uniform vec4    ambientColor;
uniform vec4    diffuseColor;   
uniform vec4    specularColor;

varying  vec3 transformedNormal;
varying  vec3 lightDir;


void main(void)
{ 
  // Dot product gives us diffuse intensity
  float diff = max(0.0, dot(normalize(transformedNormal), normalize(lightDir)));

  // Multiply intensity by diffuse color, force alpha to 1.0
  vec4 out_color = diff * diffuseColor;

  // Add in ambient light
  out_color += ambientColor;


      // Specular Light
  vec3 vReflection = normalize(reflect(-normalize(lightDir), normalize(transformedNormal)));
  float spec = max(0.0, dot(normalize(transformedNormal), vReflection));
  if(diff != 0.0) {
    float fSpec = pow(spec, 128.0);
    out_color.rgb += vec3(fSpec, fSpec, fSpec);
  }


  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0, 1.0);

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the smartness of your GLSL compiler, I think. In your fragment shader you assign a constant color to `gl_FragColor` in the last line. Therefore all your nice computations, and all the varyings get optimized away. So as `transformedNormal` has been optimized away, you also don't need to compute its value in the vertex shader. So your `v_normal` attribute is also optimized away (isn't it nice how smart your GLSL compiler is, to reduce both shaders to a single line). That's the reason it's called `ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES` and not just `ATTRIBUTES` or `DECLARED_ATTRIBUTES` (those constants don't exist, I made them up).

Try to assign `out_color` to `gl_FragColor` and nothing should get optimized away.

Comment: Oops, I knew it was something simple. I was debugging something else and changed that line as a test, I guess the issue did not exist before that change. Thanks. It would be cool if there was a way to find that out.

Comment: @nkassis: You do have a way to find out. The way you just did; OpenGL told you that an attribute is unused, by not making it active.